# Model disappear when adding a new texture opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, shader, 3dsmax

I tried to load the same model(modeled in 3Ds max) in opengl, but with different textures. The problem is, that when I try to bind the Texture with glBindTexture after I have acitvated the texture, then it disappears. Before I changed the textures in 3Ds max, it always has show me the model in black color (just in opengl). But I haven´t even assign black color to my model. My image "model-image.png" also contains all textures, that I have assign to my object. So am I missing something?
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
void initDrawing()
{
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
program = glCreateProgram();
    std::string shaderV = Utilities::loadFile("shader.vert");
    std::string shaderF = Utilities::loadFile("shader.frag");
    program = Utilities::compileShader(shaderV, shaderF);
    Utilities::loadObj("model.obj", obj);
    Utilities::loadPNG("model-image.png", diffuse);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayObject);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vPosition);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vPosition);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec4)*obj.vertices.size(), &obj.vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    GLuint vCoordinates;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vCoordinates);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vCoordinates);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec2)*obj.textureCoordinates.size(), &obj.textureCoordinates[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vCoordinates);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    glGenTextures(2, &texture);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, diffuse.width, diffuse.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        &diffuse.colors[0]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    glUseProgram(program);

    ModelView = glGetUniformLocation(program, "ModelView");
    Projection = glGetUniformLocation(program, "Projection");
    Diffuse = glGetUniformLocation(program, "Diffuse");
}
void display()
{

    // background color
    const GLfloat color[] = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1 };
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    modelView = view * model;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelView, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelView));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(Projection, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
    glUniform1i(Diffuse, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, obj.vertices.size());

glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

My Shader:

fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D Diffuse;

in vec2 fUV;
out vec3 color;

//main for the color
void main(void)
{
    color = texture(Diffuse, fUV).rgb; 
}
```

vertex Shader:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec4 vPosition;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 vCoordinates;

uniform mat4 ModelView;
uniform mat4 Projection;

out vec2 fUV;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = Projection * ModelView * vPosition;
    fUV = vCoordinates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you say

```
layout(location = 2) in vec2 vCoordinates;
```

you really mean to say

```
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vCoordinates;
```

considering you never enable vertex attribute 2.

Comment: Oh thanks @TheKitchenSink ,yes I mean location = 1 you´re right. That solved the problem a little, so the object isn´t black anymore. But unfortunetly, it isn´t showing the model as expected. Now the textures are mixed. I also think, that I have exported the object correctly. So the problem isn´t by exporting in 3Ds Max I guess.

Comment: The other thing that this might be caused by is the fact that OpenGL loads textures "upside-down". In your vertex shader, try seting fUV.y to (1 - vCoordinates.y).